# How to compare branches using RegEx in CircleCI 2.0

Tags: circleci

How can we compare `CIRCLE_BRANCH` with a regular expression?
In `1.0` we do it by:

```
branch: /feature.*/
commands: 
  <your commands here>
```

In '2.0' `master` branch is compared as follows:

```
if [ "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}" != "master" ]; then
    <your commands>
fi
```

How can I handle `/feature.*/` in `CircleCI 2.0` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a Workflow like it is described here

https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#branch-level-job-execution

you can use

```
branch:
  only: ....
```

or

```
branch:
  ignore: ...
```